# Vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients can't be produced using a finite number of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A vector space $V$ is a set that is closed under finite vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Question :
Prove that vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients can't be produced using a finite number of polynomials.

Note 1 : I know how to prove that the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients is infinite and countable. Is it related to that problem?

Note 2 : I think  the meaning of "produce" in this question is not clear to me.

Comment: It seems "produced" means "spanned", in which case any finite number of polynomials can only span polynomials up to a certain finite order and therefore can't span the entire space of all polynomials.

Comment: @yurnero i agree with you ... but i don't know how to write it in a formal way ...

Comment: A formally written proof using that idea could start with "Take a finite set $\{p_1, p_2,\ldots, p_n\}$ of polynomials and let $n$ be the highest degree among them."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{P_1,\ldots,P_n\}$ be any finite collection of polynomials. To be concrete, let $P_i(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{m_i}a_{i,j}x^j$ with $a_{i,m_i}\neq 0$, that is $P_i$ has order $m_i$. Let $m=\max\{m_1,\ldots,m_n\}$. Then, for all scalars $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n,$ we note
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_iP_i(x)
$$ 
is a polynomial with order at most $m$. In particular, $P_0(x)\equiv x^{m+1}$ cannot be in the span of $\{P_1,\ldots,P_n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The degree of possible polynomials is unbounded. The degree of the polynomials in a basis is bounded. Moreover the linear combination of polynomials of degree at most n is easily shown to have degree at most n. So any finite set of polynomials cannot span the set of all polynomials. Noteworthy is that as a vector space the polynomials are isomorphic to R^e_n .